# Who can add verses to vedas?

Tags: vedas, sruti

As vedas are considered to be 'srutis' (i.e. something that is heard), my question is how do we decide if some individual proposes couple of verses claiming that it was revealed to him while in meditation. Can these be added ?
Is there a criterion ? If so where is it mentioned ?

Comment: Dup. of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26441/who-were-the-vedic-composers-qualitatively

Comment: Brahmrishis are one of them as Vishwamitra got privilege to add verse in Veda after becoming Brahmrishis...